# CKEditor Toolbar Configuration

Tags: javascript, wysiwyg

I would like to use CKEditor on my Drupal website. But the toolbar is not showing up when I go to edit appearance on any profile (full or advanced). Although, when I add or edit any type of content, the toolbar is shown correctly and I don't have any problems there. Just when I try to configure the toolbar.

I took a picture so that you can see exactly what I have:

[image: The error, toolbar not shown]

I also have these errors:
[image: JQueryUI errors]

It seems that the problem might have something to do with JQueryUI according to the errors I have. I use JQueryUpdate  to manage my JQuery version (which is 1.10).
I tried uninstalling CKEditor, clearing caches but it's not doing anything.
I use Drupal 7.41.

I know that this question has already been posted on this website, but after having read the answers it got I still have my problem so, sorry for the duplicate...

Thanks a lot for your answers  :)

Answer (score 1):

Ok I've just found the error. It seems that when I extracted my compressed version of my website, it renamed every folder in lowercase. So Drupal couldn't find jqueryUI folder, because it was renamed jqueryui.